# How to install Docker on Windows Server 2016 without Internet?

Tags: windows-installation, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to install docker on a Windows Server 2016 VM that's not connected to the internet. The official docker documentation doesn't give any advice for installing on a Windows Server 2016 VM without the internet, so how can I achieve this?

I read a blog somewhere that said it was sufficient to download the docker.exe and dockerd.exe files and place them in C:\Windows\System32, then running `dockerd.exe --register-service` was sufficient to install Docker. While this appears to have "worked" (`docker info` has output), trying to pull down an image from my local registry fails (it just freezes with no error output). Additionally, I notice that there is no DockerNAT NIC setup, and I'm going to guess that there are other steps missing that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Docker website actually documented the entire process.

> 1. In a PowerShell command prompt, download the installer archive on a machine that has a connection.

```
invoke-webrequest -UseBasicparsing -Outfile docker-17.06.2-ee-7.zip https://download.docker.com/components/engine/windows-server/17.06/docker-17.06.2-ee-7.zip
```

> 2. Copy the zip file to the machine where you want to install Docker. In a PowerShell command prompt, use the following commands to extract the archive, register, and start the Docker service.

```
# Extract the archive.
Expand-Archive docker-17.06.2-ee-7.zip -DestinationPath $Env:ProgramFiles

# Clean up the zip file.
Remove-Item -Force docker-17.06.2-ee-7.zip

# Install Docker. This requires rebooting.
$null = Install-WindowsFeature containers

# Add Docker to the path for the current session.
$env:path += ";$env:ProgramFiles\docker"

# Optionally, modify PATH to persist across sessions.
$newPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\docker;" +
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",
[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $newPath,
[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

# Register the Docker daemon as a service.
dockerd --register-service

# Start the Docker service.
Start-Service docker
```

> 3. Test your Docker EE installation by running the hello-world container.

```
docker container run hello-world:nanoserver
```

[Install Docker Enterprise Edition for Windows Server](https://docs.docker.com/install/windows/docker-ee/)

Since you failed to provide what version of Windows Server you are using the following information might be relevant.

> Docker Universal Control Plane is not currently supported on Windows
>   Server 1709 due to image incompatibility issues. To use UCP, for now,
>   use the current LTSB Windows release and not 1709.

Comment: @dennis_ler - Docker has changed a great deal in 3 years.  Since the question was specifically about Docker Enterprise I can't exactly update my answer.  However, the basic idea, would be identical you would just point to a different archive.

Comment: Commentary should be left to actionable improvements with regards to the answer.  [Here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) is the documentation today.